# Python Crawler Beatifulsoup decompose() function

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing, web-crawler

I am having trouble to get the decompose() function working in my crawler which I am making with python and BeautifulSoup.

The problem is as follow. I am trying to get all the specification data from a websites product (which you can see in the source code):

```
soup = soup_function('http://www.processorstore.nl/product/476816/category-212194/intel-core-i7-4790k.html')
dt = soup.findAll('dt', {'class': 'product-specs--item-title'})

for i in range(0, len(dt)):

    dtRows = dt[i]
    dtRowsStrip = dtRows.text.strip()

    print(dtRows.text.strip())

    # print(dtRows)

    # dtRowsSplit = "".join(dtRowsStrip.split())
    # print(dtRowsSplit)
```

when I use the:

```
> print(dtRows.text.strip())
```

I get as output, this:

```
Serie
Threads
Socket
Kloksnelheid
Fabrikantcode
Artikelnummer
Merk
Garantie
Garantietype
Serie           


        Serie
Socket          


        Socket
Codenaam            


        Codenaam
Threads         


        Threads
Turbo Frequency         


        Turbo Frequency
Multiplier unlocked         


        Multiplier unlocked
Cache           


        Cache
Geheugencontroller          


        Geheugencontroller
etc ....
```

The first complete row it is correct. At the seccond Row I get Double Values because of a `<a>` Tag within the `<dt>` Tag.

One example is this:

```
<dt class="product-specs--item-title">
    <a class="product-specs--help-icon js-tooltip" href="#spec_Serie" title="Zowel AMD als Intel produceren processoren in verschillende series. Een serie is bedoeld voor bepaald gebruik. Zo zijn Core i3 processoren geschikt voor internet &amp; office werkzaamheden en Core i7 processoren voor veeleisende multitasking en gaming. Binnen een serie zijn verschillende modellen processoren verkrijgbaar. Van welke serie is deze processor onderdeel?"><i class="icon icon-circle-questionmark"></i><span class="product-specs--help-title">Serie</span></a>
    <span>Serie</span>
</dt>
```

Can someone help me to delete the complete `<a>` tag?

ADDITIONAL INFO:

#

If I use the following code:

```
    soup = soup_function('http://www.processorstore.nl/product/476816/category-212194/intel-core-i7-4790k.html')

for spec in soup.select('dt.product-specs--item-title'):
    print(spec.get_text(strip=True))
```

The output is as Follow:

```
Serie
Threads
Socket
Kloksnelheid
Fabrikantcode
Artikelnummer
Merk
Garantie
Garantietype
SerieSerie
SocketSocket
CodenaamCodenaam
ThreadsThreads
Turbo FrequencyTurbo Frequency
Multiplier unlockedMultiplier unlocked
CacheCache
GeheugencontrollerGeheugencontroller
ProductieprocesProductieproces
Stroomverbruik maximaalStroomverbruik maximaal
KloksnelheidKloksnelheid
ProcessorkernenProcessorkernen
Type GPUType GPU
```

As you can see. after the second `<dl>` block I get double values.

ADDITIONAL: 
Thank you... I also just found it out. I know your code is better but just wanted to share my solution:

```
    for spec in soup.select('div.product-specs dl.product-specs--list > dt.product-specs--item-title span.product-specs--help-title'):
    print(spec.get_text(strip=True))

    parent = spec.find_parent('dt')
    value = parent.find_next_sibling("dd", {'class': 'product-specs--item-spec'})
    print(value.text.strip())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to be more specific about where and what nodes you are extracting:

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen('http://www.processorstore.nl/product/476816/category-212194/intel-core-i7-4790k.html'))

for spec in soup.select('div.product-specs > dl.product-specs--list > dt.product-specs--item-title'):
    print spec.get_text(strip=True)
```

Prints:

```
Serie
Threads
Socket
Kloksnelheid
```

Here, we are basically getting the following block:

[image]

---

If you need to get all of the product specs and avoid duplicates, you need to go one level down to `span` with `class="product-specs--help-title"`:

```
for spec in soup.select('div.product-specs dl.product-specs--list > dt.product-specs--item-title span.product-specs--help-title'):
    print spec.get_text(strip=True)
```

Prints:

```
Serie
Socket
Codenaam
Threads
Turbo Frequency
Multiplier unlocked
Cache
Geheugencontroller
Productieproces
Stroomverbruik maximaal
Kloksnelheid
Processorkernen
Type GPU
Koeler meegeleverd
```

---

Here is how you get the name:value pairs of specs:

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen('http://www.processorstore.nl/product/476816/category-212194/intel-core-i7-4790k.html'))

for spec in soup.select('div.product-specs dl.product-specs--list > dt.product-specs--item-title'):
    name = spec.span
    if not name:
        continue

    value = spec.find_next_sibling('dd', class_='product-specs--item-spec')
    print name.get_text(strip=True), value.get_text(strip=True)
```

Prints:

```
Serie Core i7
Socket 1150
Codenaam Haswell Refresh
Threads 8
Turbo Frequency 4400 MHz
Multiplier unlocked Ja
Cache 8 MB
Geheugencontroller DDR3-1600
Productieproces 22 nm
Stroomverbruik maximaal 88 watt
Kloksnelheid 4000 MHz
Processorkernen Quad-core
Type GPU Intel HD Graphics 4600
Koeler meegeleverd Ja
```

Comment: the first rows arent the problem. At the second <dl the values are double. If i use "dtRowsSplit = "".join(dtRowsStrip.split())" i get this:
TurboFrequencyTurboFrequency, 
MultiplierunlockedMultiplierunlocked     IF i can delete the <a tag i'll get the value just once

Comment: I still get the values, double. I'll add the additional code to the Post

Comment: Now i have another problem. :( Before i had the following: dd = dt.find_next_sibling("dd", {'class': 'product-specs--item-spec'})   Now i can't get the propper value with the it.   Serie == Core i7 ... Could you help me out one last time please

Comment: @FrEaKi also, I've noticed that you've also previously asked questions, but haven't accepted the answers. Please fix it (click the checkbox near the answer that deserves it). Thank you for understanding.